# how to create a custom graphic border from a path?

Tags: gimp, path, drawing, path-effects

I would like to create some custom graphical border painted along paths, but I don't knew how or where to start. I Knew how to use gimp and other graphical softwares but mostly I only do photo Manipulations.
Here is the look what I would like to re-create, more or less.

[image: Example Border]

can anyone give me a hint, how to achive this?

Comment: Did you search Google? I did and found several how-to's – the top link was even from GIMP itself. If you tried those methods but they did not work for your purposes, you might want to add that to your question (also include why, of course).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trace pattern along a path in GIMP?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/96293/how-to-trace-pattern-along-a-path-in-gimp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `Edit>Stroke path`:

- In `Line` mode, the line is filled with a pattern (but the pattern is not rotated to follow the path)
- In `Brush` mode, the brush is used to paint along the path, and you can set `Emulate brush dynamics` using a Dynamics setting that tracks the path direction to rotate the brush.

You can also use [ofn-gradient-along-path](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-path-tools/files/scripts/) to stroke a path with a transversal gradient.